# Is it possible to use each and keyup function nested?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use the each function because it has more than one input. I need to use the keyup function within each input.  But is it possible to use each and keyup function nested? The keyup function does not work.Is there an error in coding? The following two code examples did not work for the keyup function.

```
  $(".my-input").each(function () {
  var txtvalue = $(this).val();
  $('.my-input').keyup( function () {                  
  if (txtvalue == "") {
  //the code
  } else {
  //the code
  }
  }) })
```

> or

```
  $('.my-input').keyup(function () {
  $(".my-input").each(function () {
  debugger;
  var txtvalue = $(this).val();
  if (txtvalue == "") {
  //the code           
  } else {
  //the code
  }
  })
  })
```

Comment: did you try replace `$('.my-input').keyup` with `$(this).keyup` ? (in first chunk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is you are getting the value before the keyup, at that point - there is no text in the input field. You need to move that inside the keyup method. Like this:

```
$(".my-input").each(function () {
  $(this).keyup( function () {    
    var txtvalue = $(this).val();
    console.log(txtvalue);
  }) 
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4taa1y9/). I put in tempid's to display that it is getting the different fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a parameter `event` to function `.keyup(event)`. Than process this value as you wish. look at example snippet:

```js
$(".my-input").each(function () {
  $('.my-input').keyup( function (e) {                  
     $(".res").html(e.which);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="my-input">
<input type="text" class="my-input">
<input type="text" class="my-input">
<input type="text" class="my-input">
<div class="res"></div>
```